# Mysterious Xcode linker error after updating Architectures to 64-bit (standard)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, 64-bit

I updated my target's Architectures build setting from "Standard 32-bit" to Standard (64-bit) and now I'm getting mysterious Xcode linker errors so that I can't build the project successfully. For example:

- `Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

or:

- `File too small for architecture x86_64`

... or similar.

What do I do now?

Comment: Suggestion - update your question with examples of the errors. Self-answered questions need to conform to the same standards as any other question.

Comment: @rmaddy sure, I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that if you are planning to change your target's Architectures build setting (because you are updating from 32-bit to 64-bit), you should proceed as follows:

1. Compile (successfully).
2. Change the architectures.
3. Compile again.

The reason is that if you omit step 1 and just change the architectures, and if you then omit step 3 so that you edit the code and compile and *fail* (because you have introduced a compiler error into your code), Xcode will subsequently be unable to compile *at all* because the incomplete compilation causes an Xcode Linker error.

Okay, so you *didn't* do that, and now you *are* getting the Xcode Linker error. Here's how to correct the situation: Hold down the Option key and choose Product > Clean Build Folder. This will delete the remnants of the incomplete compilation. Now compile again, and the linker error will go away.

Comment: What if we just change the architecture, restart xcode & then clean & build. Will it not work that way?

Comment: @iYoung I don't know. What I know is that what I did, didn't work and I ended up with these mysterious errors, and this is how I fixed it.